# Iphone / Ipad like, Icon shaking Effect jquery / CSS3

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions, jquery-effects

i already tried to searching on Google for Shaking effect / Dancing icon/object effect but i cannot get a good answer,

how to create an shaking/dancing animation, just like what we see in iphone/ipad when we touch and hold an app icon,

Thank you in advance

Regards, Yongki

.........................................................................................

i just got the best plugin to create that effect, here http://jackrugile.com/jrumble/

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just got the best plugin to create that effect,
here http://jackrugile.com/jrumble/

Thank you